# Using github.com/icza/minquery to directly query page 3 value

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I wanna confirm the right way to get skip(3) values using minquery, 1. foreach skip, get 1,2,3 page data, then return the 3rd value? or 2. use a way to get the cursor of skip(3). if the 2rd is right, how to get the cursor of skip(3) page? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't skip documents directly using [`github.com/icza/minquery`](https://github.com/icza/minquery). The purpose of `minquery` is to not have to use [`Query.Skip()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Query.Skip) (because that becomes less efficient when the number of "skippable" documents grows). The only way to skip 3 documents is to query for more than 3, and throw away the first 3.

`minquery` is for cases where you don't have to skip the initial documents. `minquery` requires you to iterate over the documents, and acquire the cursor that encodes the index entry of the last returned document (this cursor is returned to you by `MinQuery.All()`). When you need the next page, you have to use the cursor you acquired in the previous query, and then it can list subsequent documents without having to skip anything, because the encoded index entry can be used to jump right where the last query finished listing documents.

Think of GMail: you can always jump just to the *next* (and previous) page of emails, but you have no way of "magically" jumping to the 10th or 100th page: GMail uses the same mechanism under the hood.

Comment: thank you for your answers, is that means, if request page 3, I still need to get the documents from page 1, 2 and use the second cursor to retrieve page 3 documents?

Comment: @sophiageng If you need page 3, you should already have a cursor returned by minquery when you requested page 2, so you should just set that, and you will get documents right of page 3. If you don't have any cursors and you still need page 3, then run a single query that contains the documents of the first 3 pages, discard documents of the first 2 pages and use the third.

Comment: yes, I need to get previous cursor by query method, thank you all.

Comment: and another question, the cursorfield, because I have access customer query condition to query paged document, how to create index in MongoDB, should I create all the scenarios index?

Comment: @sophiageng See [Index Intersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/) and [Create Indexes to Support Your Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/).

Comment: I mean the cursorfield must totally consistent  with the index created in MongoDB?

Comment: @sophiageng Yes, they must match.

Comment: got it. Thanks.